# React router 1.0 pass multiple props to children routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm using react-router 1.0 and react-redux on an app, and I'm wondering what strategy is best to pass props to children on larger apps. Here's a basic situation:

Let's say I have a route `/admin/users/edit/:id` with the following structure on its components:

Routes:

```jsx
<Router>
  <Route path="admin" component={Admin}>
    <Route path="users" component={Users}>
      <Route path="edit/:id" component={Edit}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Admin:

```jsx
class Admin extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      {this.props.children}
    )
  }
}
```

Users:

```jsx
class User extends React.Component {

  edit = (id, params) => {
    const { dispatch } this.props;
    dispatch(edit(id, params));
  } 

  other functions (add, remove) ...

  render() {
    return (
      {this.props.children}
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { users } = state;
  return { users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(User);
```

Edit:

```jsx
class Edit extends React.Component {

  submit () => {
    const { id } = this.props.params;
    const { firstName } = this.refs;
    this.props.edit(id, {firstName: firstName.value});
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props.params;
    const user = this.props.users[id];
    return (
       <form>
         <input ref='firstName' defaultValue={user.firstName}/>
         <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
       </form>
    )
  }
}
```

How would I pass the users & edit function props down to the children?

I know about `React.cloneElement()` (as in https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/passing-props-to-children), but if I have multiple routes like `/users/add`, `/users/remove/:id`, etc, I would be passing and exposing all the functions (edit, add, remove...) to all children. That solution doesn't seem to work very well when you have more than one children.

I would like to keep my children as dumb as possible, and use this same structure across the application (`/images/add`, `/images/remove/:id`, etc).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

#### First level children:

Use [`React.cloneElement()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement), that's something you are already aware of. I wouldn't use it for deeply nested Components though.

#### To all routes:

Use [`createElement()`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props):

```jsx
<Router createElement={createElement} />

// default behavior
function createElement(Component, props) {
  // make sure you pass all the props in!
  return <Component {...props}/>
}

// maybe you're using something like Relay
function createElement(Component, props) {
  // make sure you pass all the props in!
  return <RelayContainer Component={Component} routerProps={props}/>
}
```

Check more on that in the [React Router docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props).

#### Use context:

> **Note:**
>   Context is an advanced and experimental feature. The API is likely to change in future releases.

See how to use it in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

---

There is also the whole thread about it in the [react-router#1531](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1531).